Unable to retrieve key vault certificates in azure runbook
I am trying to access key vault certificates inside of Azure runbook, in a new Runtime environment experience. But for some reason, it is not allowing me to list the same.
This is the command that is returning null.
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -Verbose).context
$certficate = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $vaultName -Name $certificateName

But running the same command using local or cloud powershell, I am able to access the key vault certificate.
Runbook environment used has following specs:
Powershell Version: 5.1
Modules Attached: Az, ExchangeOnlineManagement

I have tried both RBAC access and access policy approach for key vault. Using access policy approach, I have given read and list certificate permission to managed identity for automation account. And using RBAC approach, I have assigned automation account, both Key Vault Certificates Officer and Key Vault Reader role. I even tried using user assigned identity for automation account with key vault reader permission.
It doesn't throw any error too, like some permission is missing or incorrect configs, just null value for certificate.
If anyone has experience with this or suggestions on what might be going wrong, I'd appreciate your help.

EDIT
The following is a screenshot of the dependencies of the runtime environment with their respective versions.

Additional Note: The UI of this page is also broken, preventing direct access to the package details due to issues with inline CSS. I have temporarily modified the browser’s CSS to view it. If anyone knows the proper channel to report this UI issue, that would be helpful. To recreate, just click on any azure runtime environment, you won't be able to see any dependency. I was planning on reporting it as well but am currently focused on resolving the main issue mentioned above.
The debug log for the execution of Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate is attached below (no errors or anything out of ordinary is displayed). I hope it helps someone familiar with its internal workings to identify the root cause.
Loading module from path 'C:\usr\src\PSModules\Az.KeyVault\KeyVault.Autorest\bin\Az.KeyVault.private.dll'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-CmdletSurface'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-ExampleStub'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-FormatPs1xml'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-HelpMarkdown'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-ModelSurface'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-ProxyCmdlet'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-Psd1'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-TestStub'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-CommonParameter'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-ModuleGuid'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-ScriptCmdlet'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-ParameterForRegion'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmRegion_List'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_Get'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_GetViaIdentity'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_List'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_List1'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmNameAvailability_CheckExpanded'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmNameAvailability_CheckViaJsonFilePath'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmNameAvailability_CheckViaJsonString'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultNameAvailability_CheckExpanded'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultNameAvailability_CheckViaJsonFilePath'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultNameAvailability_CheckViaJsonString'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_Update'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_UpdateExpanded'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_UpdateViaIdentity'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_UpdateViaIdentityExpanded'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_UpdateViaJsonFilePath'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_UpdateViaJsonString'.
Loading module from path 'C:\usr\src\PSModules\Az.KeyVault\KeyVault.Autorest\custom\Az.KeyVault.custom.psm1'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-CmdletSurface'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-ExampleStub'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-FormatPs1xml'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-HelpMarkdown'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-ModelSurface'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-ProxyCmdlet'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-Psd1'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-TestStub'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-CommonParameter'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-ModuleGuid'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-ScriptCmdlet'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-ParameterForRegion'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmRegion_List'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_Get'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_GetViaIdentity'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_List'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_List1'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmNameAvailability_CheckExpanded'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmNameAvailability_CheckViaJsonFilePath'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmNameAvailability_CheckViaJsonString'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultNameAvailability_CheckExpanded'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultNameAvailability_CheckViaJsonFilePath'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultNameAvailability_CheckViaJsonString'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_Update'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_UpdateExpanded'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_UpdateViaIdentity'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_UpdateViaIdentityExpanded'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_UpdateViaJsonFilePath'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_UpdateViaJsonString'.
Loading module from path 'C:\usr\src\PSModules\Az.KeyVault\KeyVault.Autorest\internal\Az.KeyVault.internal.psm1'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-CmdletSurface'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-ExampleStub'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-FormatPs1xml'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-HelpMarkdown'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-ModelSurface'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-ProxyCmdlet'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-Psd1'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-TestStub'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-CommonParameter'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-ModuleGuid'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-ScriptCmdlet'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-ParameterForRegion'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmRegion_List'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_Get'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_GetViaIdentity'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_List'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_List1'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmNameAvailability_CheckExpanded'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmNameAvailability_CheckViaJsonFilePath'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmNameAvailability_CheckViaJsonString'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultNameAvailability_CheckExpanded'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultNameAvailability_CheckViaJsonFilePath'.
Importing cmdlet 'Test-AzKeyVaultNameAvailability_CheckViaJsonString'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_Update'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_UpdateExpanded'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_UpdateViaIdentity'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_UpdateViaIdentityExpanded'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_UpdateViaJsonFilePath'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm_UpdateViaJsonString'.
Exporting function 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm'.
Exporting function 'Get-ParameterForRegion'.
Exporting function 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm'.
Importing function 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm'.
Importing function 'Get-ParameterForRegion'.
Importing function 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm'.
Exporting function 'Add-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmRegion'.
Exporting function 'Remove-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmRegion'.
Importing function 'Add-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmRegion'.
Importing function 'Remove-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmRegion'.
Exporting function 'Add-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmRegion'.
Exporting function 'Remove-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmRegion'.
Exporting function 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmRegion'.
Exporting function 'Test-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmNameAvailability'.
Exporting function 'Test-AzKeyVaultNameAvailability'.
Loading module from path 'C:\usr\src\PSModules\Az.KeyVault\Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.KeyVault.dll'.
Importing cmdlet 'Add-AzKeyVaultCertificate'.
Importing cmdlet 'Backup-AzKeyVaultCertificate'.
Importing cmdlet 'Add-AzKeyVaultCertificateContact'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultCertificateContact'.
Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzKeyVaultCertificateContact'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultCertificateOperation'.
Importing cmdlet 'Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultCertificateIssuer'.
Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzKeyVaultCertificateIssuer'.
Importing cmdlet 'Set-AzKeyVaultCertificateIssuer'.
Importing cmdlet 'New-AzKeyVaultCertificatePolicy'.
Importing cmdlet 'Set-AzKeyVaultCertificatePolicy'.
Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzKeyVaultCertificate'.
Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzKeyVaultCertificateOperation'.
Importing cmdlet 'Restore-AzKeyVaultCertificate'.
Importing cmdlet 'Stop-AzKeyVaultCertificateOperation'.
Importing cmdlet 'Undo-AzKeyVaultCertificateRemoval'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultCertificate'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVault'.
Importing cmdlet 'New-AzKeyVault'.
Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzKeyVault'.
Importing cmdlet 'Undo-AzKeyVaultRemoval'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVault'.
Importing cmdlet 'Add-AzKeyVaultKey'.
Importing cmdlet 'Backup-AzKeyVaultKey'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultKey'.
Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzKeyVaultKey'.
Importing cmdlet 'Restore-AzKeyVaultKey'.
Importing cmdlet 'Undo-AzKeyVaultKeyRemoval'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultKey'.
Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm'.
Importing cmdlet 'Undo-AzKeyVaultManagedHsmRemoval'.
Importing cmdlet 'Add-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount'.
Importing cmdlet 'Backup-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageSasDefinition'.
Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount'.
Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageSasDefinition'.
Importing cmdlet 'Restore-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount'.
Importing cmdlet 'Set-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageSasDefinition'.
Importing cmdlet 'Undo-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccountRemoval'.
Importing cmdlet 'Undo-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageSasDefinitionRemoval'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccountKey'.
Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy'.
Importing cmdlet 'Backup-AzKeyVaultSecret'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultSecret'.
Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzKeyVaultSecret'.
Importing cmdlet 'Restore-AzKeyVaultSecret'.
Importing cmdlet 'Set-AzKeyVaultSecret'.
Importing cmdlet 'Undo-AzKeyVaultSecretRemoval'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultSecret'.
Importing cmdlet 'Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy'.
Importing cmdlet 'Add-AzKeyVaultNetworkRule'.
Importing cmdlet 'New-AzKeyVaultNetworkRuleSetObject'.
Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzKeyVaultNetworkRule'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultNetworkRuleSet'.
Importing cmdlet 'Export-AzKeyVaultSecurityDomain'.
Importing cmdlet 'Import-AzKeyVaultSecurityDomain'.
Importing cmdlet 'New-AzKeyVaultCertificateAdministratorDetail'.
Importing cmdlet 'New-AzKeyVaultCertificateOrganizationDetail'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultCertificatePolicy'.
Importing cmdlet 'Backup-AzKeyVault'.
Importing cmdlet 'Restore-AzKeyVault'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm'.
Importing cmdlet 'New-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultManagedHsm'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultRoleAssignment'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultRoleDefinition'.
Importing cmdlet 'New-AzKeyVaultRoleDefinition'.
Importing cmdlet 'New-AzKeyVaultRoleAssignment'.
Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzKeyVaultRoleAssignment'.
Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzKeyVaultRoleDefinition'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultSetting'.
Importing cmdlet 'Update-AzKeyVaultSetting'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultRandomNumber'.
Importing cmdlet 'Invoke-AzKeyVaultKeyOperation'.
Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzKeyVaultKeyRotationPolicy'.
Importing cmdlet 'Set-AzKeyVaultKeyRotationPolicy'.
Importing cmdlet 'Invoke-AzKeyVaultKeyRotation'.
Importing alias 'Set-AzKeyVaultCertificateAttribute'.
Importing alias 'Set-AzKeyVaultKey'.
Importing alias 'Set-AzKeyVaultKeyAttribute'.
Importing alias 'Set-AzKeyVaultSecretAttribute'.
Importing alias 'Set-AzKeyVaultRoleDefinition'.




Could you check and confirm all modules are up to date or not? Please include response image by editing your question?

@Sridevi Thanks for looking into it. Yes, everything is upto date. I have attached the screenshot as requested.

@Sridevi It has been solved. The issue was the incompatibility of powershell 5.1 with Az module above v8 or so. Needed to downgrade it to 6.5.0


PowerShell 5.1 is an older version that doesn't fully support the features and changes introduced in newer Az module versions (8.x and above).

In your case, the error occurred as there is incompatibility of PowerShell 5.1 with Az module above v8. To resolve the error, try downgrading the Az module to earlier version like version 6.5.0.
I have one Azure Key Vault with certificate named sricert0310 in it as below:

To retrieve these details in Azure runbook, I assigned same roles as you to managed identity under Key Vault like this:

When I ran the below PowerShell script with runbook having Az modules of compatible versions, I got the response successfully:
$vaultName = "kvname"
$certificateName = "certname"

$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -Verbose).context
$certificate = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $vaultName -Name $certificateName

$certificate

Response:


It resolved the issue @Sridevi. This would have been much easier to resolve if the error handling or doc is improved a bit regarding compatibility between each module and powershell environment. But maybe it is not that straightforward to implement. Whatever the case, thanks a lot.
